# git rebase -i foo/dev gives noop

Tags: git, dvcs

When I try to get into the interactive rebase mode as explained [here](http://schacon.github.io/gitbook/4_interactive_rebasing.html), all I'm getting is **noop** which is weird but I cannot figure out why.

I am inside a temp branch in my machine and when I try to view the difference between, I get this:

```
Tugberk@TUGBERKPC /D/Dropbox/AppsPublic/gulp-aspnet-k (temp-a)
$ git log --pretty=oneline  temp-a..ajryan/dev
f0ef4ee40fde4de5360515fd556de9c3ed40431c update readme with new optionsfcba1ae3306ae041a1d82647e4cf65a0c96fe2f7 do not loop for build, restore8bedd238660908f06d698815ef12fce786d716ed fix command concat
e2e3a0d00e3950911c00c0e6e51a671f5f2ac2d3 bump version
d65923ff91eb9d6b9782bc2bf5ab606d19733203 add quiet option
91a1faff0a3aa1ca552df2151190a3ecd87cfc6f allow caller to loop all comma962c55854457314324d81457c42913532875cc85 trailing whitespace, tabs > sp
```

However, when I run the following command, I'm getting noop:

```
Tugberk@TUGBERKPC /D/Dropbox/AppsPublic/gulp-aspnet-k (temp-a)
$ git rebase -i ajryan/dev
```

Any idea why and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: if `temp-a` is an ancestor of `ajryan/dev` then this is expected I think.

Answer (score 4):

Your `git log` command is showing commits that are on `ajryan/dev` but not on `temp-a`.  Your `rebase` command is told to rebase commits that are on `temp-a` but not on `ajryan/dev`, but presumably there are no such commits.  Pictorially:

```
... - o - o - o                   <-- HEAD=temp-a
                \
                  o - o - o - *   <-- ajryan/dev
```

Therefore, there are no commits to pick up and rebase onto the commit I have marked with a star `*`.  So `rebase -i` generates a single no-op command.

If you execute that no-op, the rebase operation should conclude by moving `temp-a` to point the last commit added on after `*`, which should make `temp-a` point to commit `*`.  (If that doesn't happen, it's a small bug in `rebase`.)  If you delete the no-op, though, the rebase operation will be aborted, and `temp-a` will not be moved.

---

Note that if you *did* have different items on `temp-a` you could rebase them, or rebase the other branch.  Here are two more illustrations, starting with almost the same base, but with one commit that's on `temp-a` that is not on `ajryan/dev`:

```
... - o - o - o - @               <-- HEAD=temp-a
                \
                  o - o - o - *   <-- ajryan/dev
```

In this case, you can either put the `@` commit on top of the other commits:

```
... - o - o - o
                \                     (illustration 1)
                  o - o - o - * - @
```

or at the bottom, below the other commits:

```
... - o - o - o
                \                     (illustration 2)
                  @ - o - o - o - *
```

Here I have left out the labels (`temp-a` and `ajryan/dev`).  This is on purpose: in git, branch labels are easy to move around (and are actually *expected* to move as long as it's in a "forward" fashion); all of the actual branch-iness is stored in the commits themselves.  What `git rebase` really does is *copy* old commits to new ones, so that you can change their parent-age and/or contents.

In Illustration #1, we've re-parented commit `@`: it now has commit `*` as its parent.  All the other commits are unchanged, and hence only commit `@` has to be copied.

In Illustration #2, however, we've re-parented the entire chain of commits that were originally only on `ajryan/dev`.  Commit `@` itself is unchanged, but we had to copy all four of the original `o - o - o - *` commits: we copy the first `o` to set its parent to `@`.  This new commit has a new and different SHA-1 ID, so we copy the second `o` to use the new commit's ID as its parent.  This second copy forces the third copy, which then forces the last copy of the `*` commit.  See the next section as to what can be bad about that.

---

In git, to join two different chains of commits, you would normally use `git merge`:

```
          A - B
        /       \
... - o           M   <-- HEAD=branch
        \       /
          C - D
```

Here merge commit `M` joins the two chains `A - B` and `C - D` that fork off from `o`.  If all of `A` through `D` exist, and you create new commit `M`, nothing happens to `A` through `D`: they are still the same as before.

For simple development, though, it's usually nicer to "rebase" work: to make `C` and `D` sit "on top" of `A - B`.  But to do that you must *copy* the commits, because a commit in git is permanent and unchanging.  You copy `C` to a new, slightly different `C'`, and copy `D` to a new, slightly different `D'`.  The main thing that's different about `C'` is that its parent is `B`, not `o`, and the main thing that's different about `D'` is that its parent is `C'`, not `C`:

```
          A - B - C' - D'   <-- HEAD=branch
        /
... - o
        \
          C - D            [abandoned]
```

Once the rebase copy is done, you simply abandon the old `C` and `D` commits and start pretending `C'` and `D'` were the original commits:

```
          A - B - C - D   <-- HEAD=branch
        /
... - o
```

Now we no longer need the little kink in the graph since we've forgotten all about the original `C` and `D`, and history just looks like this:

```
... - o - A - B - C - D   <-- HEAD=branch
```

The dirty secret (not so secret, not that dirty) is that the original `C` and `D` are still *in there*, they're just invisible (to you).  The part that makes it truly dirty happens if *someone else* has the original two `C` and `D` commits.  Git commit IDs are cryptographic checksums of their contents, including the parent SHA-1 IDs, so the original `C` and `D` are still there and are *different* from the new `C` and `D`, and anyone else.

This matters when you pull commits from someone else: if you rebase their commits onto your work, you *change* the IDs.  You make new copies and you might forget they had the originals, but they don't know about your new copies yet and *they* have not forgotten their original IDs.

If you later present them with rebased copies of their commits, they need to do more work to pick up your copies of their commits and maybe move any additional work they've done.

In short, unless you've made arrangements with them (whoever "they" may be) in advance, a rebase like that shown in Illustration #2 is usually not a good idea.

---

What about "fast forwards"?  Well, let's take a look at Illustration #1 again.  Let's assume the `o - o - o - @` chain came from someone else (a "pull request"), and that you add commit `*` on top of it by rebasing your work onto theirs.  Let's re-draw the graph too, adding one more kink, and put the `ajryan/dev` label back:

```
... - o - o - o     [your original '@' commit, before rebasing, was here]
                \
                  o - o - o - *       <-- ajryan/dev
                                \
                                  @   <-- HEAD=(something, maybe "dev")
```

Now let's further assume that they, whoever they are, have the `o - o - o - *` sequence on their `dev` branch and have not done any additional work, so that their stuff ends at the commit marked `*`.  If you make this commit-sequence available to them, they can pick it up and add commit `@` to their `dev` branch, by simply sliding their `dev` label down-and-right to point to the `@` label.  Now let's also erase our `ajryan/dev` label, and straighten out the kinks in these drawings, and use the label `dev`.  Here's the result:

```
... - o - o - o - o - o - o - * - @   <-- HEAD=dev
```

This is what *they* will have, and what *you* will have, once you're both in sync.  It's a very simple looking history, even if it's a slight deviation from the actual development process (you wrote commit `@` without first seeing their chain that ended in `*`).  But this is the kind of "rebase" that makes following the development work a lot easier, and is in general what people want to do.

Sliding a label "rightward" (including down-and-right, or up-and-right, in drawings like these) is a "fast forward" operation.  If you run `git merge` with `--ff-only`, it will only do the "merge" if it is really this kind of non-merge fast-forward.

---

**Bottom line**: I think you wanted to rebase your `@` commit onto the `ajryan/dev` work, but you didn't *have* an `@` commit to rebase.  That's why rebase gave you a `noop`.  In this case, a simple non-merge fast-forward `git merge` suffices to make your label match their label.

---

It's also worth thinking about this: when you do `git log X..Y` you're asking git to draw the graph like I did here:

```
... - o - o - o       <-- X
        \
          o - o - o   <-- Y
```

The `X..Y` notion essentially says: starting with this graph, take out a highlighter and highlight the commit that `X` points to, and all commits left-and/or-up-or-down from there.  (That leaves the three `o`s pointed-to by `Y` un-marked.)  Then, find all commits pointed-to by `Y` that are not already highlighted, and log those.

If you reverse the `X` and `Y`, as in `git log Y..X`, you ask git to "run the highlighter" on commits marked by `Y`, which leaves only the two `o`s only on `X`, and then log all commits pointed-to by `X` that are not already highlighted.  So here you get the two `o`s on X, and none of the shared ones.

Comment: what should be the command than? `git rebase -i --onto temp-b ajryan/dev`? it doesn't work as well :s

Comment: What result would you like?  There are no commits on `temp-a` that are not already on `ajryan/dev`.  You can do a `git merge --ff-only ajryan/dev` to tell git that you'd like branch `temp-a` to catch up with `ajryan/dev` if (and only if) it can do that without making a real merge (which I believe is true, but I don't have your repo).

Comment: what I am trying to do is to get the changes made inside the remote pull-request branch into my `temp-a` branch with an interactive rebase session.

Comment: In that case, try the `git merge --ff-only` method: if it says it can't, you can do that kind of rebase to put your changes on top of their changes (see added illustration #1), or their changes on top of your changes (#2).